# Identify WW2 ammo

Tags: world-war-two, weapons, identification

I found some ammo, which I think is from World War II.

The cartridges are stamped WRA 42 and DEN 42.

I do not know what the big piece is. It has a stamp: N2117 III

Does anyone know what the big piece is?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please improve the question by telling us the scale of the ruler -- is it in centimeters, or inches?

Comment: It is in centimeters

Comment: @BruceJames  notice the "0.5m" marker near the 1. The tape must be 0.5 metres long

Answer (score 1):

From the cartridge stamps, I'd say most likely you have cartridges from Winchester Repeating Arms and [Denver Ordinance](http://metaldetectingforum.com/showthread.php?t=81741), both likely manufactured in 1942.

Comment: According to the linked forum discussion, the 42 is not the caliber - it is the year of manufacture.  Judging by the dimensions they look like .50 caliber rounds. .42 caliber would have been an extremely rare round in Europe in WWII.

Comment: @Comintern - So it does. Fixed.

Comment: @Comintern: No way that's even *near* .50 caliber. That ruler is *metric*, which puts the cartridges more in the .308 ballpark.

Comment: @DevSolar: Right you are - for some reason I was thinking the ruler was in inches.

Comment: @Comintern if it were in inches, they'd be 1" bullets, 25mm... That's a small canon, AA most likely. At 1cm, they're .306 or .308 which would be typical rifle ammo at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a fragment of an exploded mine, maybe an S-type? At the end of the war sometimes they would pile up ammo and mines into a big heap then detonate the mines all at once in an effort to destroy everything.

If you can find the center of the dump explosion, you may be able to recover a lot more stuff. Look for a crater.